# How to use Dropcam Library for iPhone app?

Tags: ios4, rtsp

I just gone through some links and libraries, and got dropcam library for rtsp streaming on iPhone. This is the link for library:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&ik=ff5f45ebb5&view=att&th=12a55cabfa24aac2&attid=0.1&disp=attd&realattid=f_gcli63610&zw

But after working on it I am unable to compile it. And also I would need some help in how it can be used.

Does anyone have idea about how it is compiled and used in Xcode project for iPhone 4.0 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know that Dropcam is a private library and Apple does not supports it. And so far today iPhone SDK does not have any library for live video streaming. Hope in future it will have.